# Pyspark error reading file. Flume HDFS sink imports file with user=flume and permissions 644

Tags: hdfs, flume, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.12

I have a Flume agent moving CSV files from spooldir source into HDFS sink. The operation works ok but the imported files have:

```
User=flume 
Group=cloudera 
Permissions=-rw-r--r--
```

The problem starts when I use Pyspark and get:

```
PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) 
cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: 
user=cloudera, access=EXECUTE, 
inode=/user/cloudera/flume/events/small.csv:cloudera:cloudera:-rw-r--r-- 
(Ancestor /user/cloudera/flume/events/small.csv is not a directory).
```

If I use "hdfs dfs -put ..." instead of Flume, user and group are "cloudera" and permissions are 777. No Spark error

[image]

What is the solution? I cannot find a way from Flume to change file's permissions. Maybe my approach is fundamentally wrong

Any ideas?

Thank you